# How to separate output records by ',' while avoiding the trailing comma in awk

Tags: awk, text-formatting

Consider the following `awk` statement and its output:

```
$ awk -F "/" '/\/tcp/ {print $1}' input_file

10\n
20\n
```

The output I want instead is:

```
10,20
```

What I tried is:

```
$ awk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ORS=","} /\/tcp/ {print $1}' input_file
10,20,
```

How do I get rid of the trailing comma ?

Comment: Try `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}$0~"tcp"{print s $1; s=","}END{print"\n"}'` (you may not want/need the `END{...}` part)

Comment: @mosvy please post that as an answer, it's a much better solution than the clunky one I came up with.

Answer (score 5):

Don't set ORS to `,` because then the output of your script doesn't end in a newline and so it's not a valid text file per POSIX and so YMMV with what other scripts you call do with it. Instead leave ORS alone so it retains whatever value it's supposed to have for your platform and print the `,` BEFORE every string you want output except for the first one:

```
awk -F '/' '/\/tcp/{printf "%s%s", sep, $1; sep=","} END{print ""}'
```

for example:

```
$ seq 3 | awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}'
1,2,3
```

Comment: +1 clean and 2 characters shorter than @mosvy's identical solution. Don't omit to add a bogus `input_file` as place-holder even though OP omitted it.

Comment: It's not quite identical to mosvy's - I'm just printing whatever value ORS has at the end of the output whereas they are printing a hard-coded `\n` under the assumption that that's what ORS was set to before they set it to null. `print ""` is always preferable to `print "\n"` when you want to output the ORS. idk if the OP has an input file or input coming from a pipe or something else so I didn't add an input file. None of that's a big deal though.

Comment: ORS always defaults to `"\n"` on all platforms. awk is a C program, and _C programs_ run using a Windows implementation translate `"\n"` to CR LF on output and the reverse on input (except if the program designates a file as 'binary' which awk wouldn't), and that applies the same to all `\n` characters -- exactly the same for `printf "\n"` as for `print ""` with `ORS==""\n"`, and exactly the same for other programs like sed and sort as for awk.

Comment: `mawk` and `gawk` have `BINMODE` variables to activate binary mode. In `mawk` if you set `BINMODE` that can also set `RS` and/or `ORS` to `\r\n`. Setting `BINMODE` in gawk doesn't set `RS` and `ORS` so instead `gawk` also provides `binmode<N>.awk` files that you can include with `-f binmode<N>.awk` to mimic what -`W BINMODE=<N>` in `mawk` does in also setting `RS` and `ORS`. So, yes, `awk` uses `\n` by default but, depending on your awk variant and the platform you're on and which options you use, if you tell `awk` to run in binary mode that can cause `RS` and/or `ORS` to have the value `\r\n`

Comment: It's also, of course, completely possible for someone to add `-v ORS='\r\n'` to a script to re-use it with DOS line endings and then if you had hard-coded `print "\n"` in your script, it's now broken vs if you used `print ""`. Sure you could change `print "\n"` to `print "\r\n"` but that's a cludge bypassing what `ORS` exists to do, i.e. specify how records are separated. To change what separates records you should be able to simply set `ORS`, not have to change hard-coded values in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would just remove the comma after printing:

```
awk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ORS=","}/\/tcp/ {print $1}' | sed 's/,$//'
```

or, to add a trailing newline:

```
awk -F "/" 'BEGIN{ORS=","}/\/tcp/ {print $1}' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

If you really want to do it in `awk`, you could try this rather inelegant approach:

```
awk -F "/" '/\/tcp/{ if(NR == 1){ printf "%s", $1} else{ printf ",%s",$1}}'
```

And, to add the trailing newline:

```
awk -F "/" '/\/tcp/{ if(NR == 1){ printf "%s", $1} else{ printf ",%s",$1}}END{print ""}'
```

Comment: Hey terdon, Thanks. I didnt even think about sed. I appreciate your help and I will just remove the comma with sed like you said.

Comment: The problem with removing the trailing `,` in that first script is that the output of the awk script isn't a valid text file per POSIX since it doesn't end in `\n` so YMMV with what any given sed will do with that as input. In practice I haven't come across any sed that'd fail with it, but I haven't tested every sed and I personally avoid creating output that's not a POSIX text file so it's highly unlikely I'd run into the problem anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, that's why I add a solution that adds a newline to all examples. However, there are valid reasons both to actively not want the newline (hashing the string, for example) or not caring about it (store in a variable), so I wouldn't add it by default. It is better to give the option and let the OP decide.

Comment: Yes, there are valid reasons to generate a string that doesn't end in `\n` but piping that string to the input of another command that per it's definition in the POSIX standard expects `\n`-terminated lines isn't one of them and I'm just not sure the OP or others reading this in future would be aware of the issue so it's worth stating. IMHO adding the newline back in with sed AFTER sed has had to read it iwithout the newline isn't a great workaround.

Answer (score 3):

A non-`awk` anwser, assuming the problem is as simple as described:

```
paste -s -d',' input_file
```

`-s, --serial` indicates that it will process the file(s) sequentially (`paste` is often used to merge lines from multiple files)

`-d, --delimiters` specifies the delimiter (default is a TAB)

Answer (score 0):

**IF you are using this in a shell** (which you didn't say, or tag), at least bash and ksh can handle it easily:

```
 foo=$( awk -F/ '/\/tcp/{print $1}' )
 # command-substitution $( .. ) trims the last newline, or more exactly
 # it trims ALL trailing newline(s), so if there was an empty last line(s) 
 # (which the example in the Q doesn't) it is/they are also discarded

 printf %s "${foo//$'\n'/,}"   # change remaining=nonfinal newlines to commas
 # and DON'T add newline; if you want ending newline make the formatstring '%s\n'
```

`$( .. )` trimming final newline(s) and `$'\n'` for newline are POSIX; on ancient shells you can use an actual newline in quotes. `${foo//old/new}` substitution is only bash and ksh (at least 93); in other shells at the cost of an extra process or two you can use

```
 printf %s "$foo" | tr '\n' ,
```

Alternatively but less aesthetically, in any POSIX shell you can use the positional parameters:

```
( set -f; IFS=$'\n'; set -- $( awk -F/ '/\/tcp/{print $1}' ); IFS=,; printf %s "$*" )
# interpolating $( .. ) with IFS set and -f enabled
# breaks it at newlines (only) and doesn't glob, so $ 1..$# are now your lines
# using $* concatenates with IFS after each value except the last
# putting it in a subshell prevents -f IFS and args changes persisting;
# unneeded in a script or function that doesn't do anything affected subsequently
```

or in bash (only?) you can simplify a bit with

```
awk -F/ '/\/tcp/{print $1}' |( readarray -t x; IFS=,; printf %s "${x[*]}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is building a single output record from the data collected across several lines.  So let's do that:

```
awk -F '/' '
    BEGIN { OFS = "," }
    /\/tcp/ { a[++n] = $1 }
    END {
        $0 = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            $i = a[i]
        print
    }' input_file
```

This collects the data into the array `a`, and in the `END` block it builds a new record with fields from this array.  At the *very* end, the record is printed.  The fields will be delimited by commas since we set `OFS` to a comma in the `BEGIN` block.

Testing:

```
$ awk -F '/' 'BEGIN {OFS=","} /\/tcp/ {a[++n]=$1} END {$0="";for (i=1;i<=n;++i) $i = a[i];print}' <<END_INPUT
first/tcp
no relevant
second/tcp
third/tcp
END_INPUT
first,second,third
```

(That last line above is the output, while the input is provided via a here-document delimited by `END_INPUT`.)