# When does OFS change?

Tags: awk

Except when set by the user or an user script, the value of OFS seems to always be an space. Even when the input use tabs:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\tthree\nfour' | awk '{NF=NF}1' | sed -n l
one$
two three$
four$
```

However, for a similar variable (ORS) it is sometimes said that: [leave ORS alone so it retains whatever value it's supposed to have for your platform](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581785/529738). I could imagine that on some platforms the default ORS could be `\r\n`. It may seem sensible on some platforms.

The question for OFS then is:

- Does OFS change between platforms ?.
- Is there some implementation where OFS is not an space ?

Edit Comment: Sorry for any confusion that my question may have generated, I hope it is clear now.

No able to up-vote (yet).

Comment: If you're asking when OFS changes automatically - it doesn;t,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I (now) commented there, ORS always defaults to `"\n"`, but on Windows the *C implementation* (which applies to many other programs in addition to awk) translates `\n` to and from CR LF -- for all `\n` characters regardless of whether they are produced from ORS, or matched to RS on input.

Similarly, **yes OFS always defaults to (one) space**. FS also defaults to one space, but is handled specially: when FS equals one space, either by default *or* explicit setting, fields are actually split by any *sequence of whitespace* (including a tab in the case you posted). Any other single-character FS is treated as a literal character, and any multi-character value as a regexp.

Thus for the single-space or regexp cases, a record may be split at delimiters which vary from field to field and/or record to record, but if you rebuild $0 by assigning to either NF as you did or any field, the rebuilt line uses the fixed value of OFS between all fields (if more than one). Also, if you use `print x,y,z` with multiple expressions, they are separated by (fixed) OFS. And of course if you explicitly print or otherwise use a string expression containing (or consisting of) OFS, you get the value of OFS.

Standardly RS can be set to any single character, or the empty string to cause 'paragraph' mode where records are split by one or more empty lines (consecutive newlines); in this mode by default it splits *fields* at newline in addition to the normal case. In *GNU* awk only, RS can be set to a multi-character regex, and the match result is available in RT. See the summary at the bottom of [this page in the GNU doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html).

Comment: +1 I did upvote your answer but the system didn't record it. Thanks!

Comment: That's all true (except it's not only GNU awk that supports multi-char RS these days, e.g. I believe mawk2 has that plus several other historically gawk extensions such as `gensub()`) but see also https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#PC-Using for when, on some platforms, RS and/or ORS automatically get set to `\r\n` when using `-W BINMODE=<N>` in mawk or `-f binmode<N>.awk` in gawk.